# Script for re-sizing a named range doesn't work dynamically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I am attempting to re-size a named range, that needs to be a very specific size (rather than just updating normally)

Cell C2 contains the size that the new range needs to be (rows) Currently = 736

Why does this work:

```
function ResizeRecordRange() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setNamedRange('RecordHistory', spreadsheet.getRange('B4:K739'));
};
```

But this not work:

```
function ResizeRecordRange() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var newLastRow = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Record").getRange('C2').getValue();
  spreadsheet.setNamedRange('RecordHistory', spreadsheet.getRange(4,2,newLastRow,10));
};
```

I expected them do both do the same thing, but the second (dynamic) version of the code returns `Cannot find method getRange(number,number,number,number).`

If it helps, I can write a quick formula into cell C2, so that it contains `B4:K739` as a string, but then I wouldn't know how to get that into the script?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so after some tinkering, this ended up working:

```
function ResizeRecordRange() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var newLastRow = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Record").getRange('C2').getValue();
  //spreadsheet.removeNamedRange('RecordHistory');
  spreadsheet.setNamedRange('RecordHistory', spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Record").getRange(4,2,newLastRow,10));
};
```